# how to open docusign clickwrap on a button click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, docusignapi

I am trying to use docusign clickwrap codes into my project. Whenever user  click a button,  then docusing clickwrap things should comes up.

But, if I use below code, It will directly opens clickwrap. How can I call ds-click using button click?

eg.

```
<button id="ds-click">click me</button>

<div id="ds-clickwrap"></div>

       <script src="https://demo.docusign.net/clickapi/sdk/latest/docusign-click.js"> 
       </script>
       <script>
         docuSignClick.Clickwrap.render({
          environment: 'https://demo.docusign.net',
          accountId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
           clickwrapId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
           clientUserId: '4x-2x4',
          documentData: {
          fullName: 'jason',
          email: 'jasion1243@gmail.com',
         company: 'xyz',
         title: 'Backend-Developer',
         date: '19/02/2023'
        }
     }, '#ds-clickwrap');
```

Answer (score 1):

The code that you have in there (`docuSignClick.Clickwrap.render` ...) is the code that shows the elastic template (formarly knonw as a clickwrap).

You can have this snippet of JavaScript called from anywhere you want in order to show the elastic template.

If you want it as a result of someone clicking a button, you can use the `onclick()` event like this:

```
<script src="https://demo.docusign.net/clickapi/sdk/latest/docusign-click.js">
<button onclick="docuSignClick.Clickwrap.render(...)">Click me</button>
```